# Запустить готовую функцию в HTML5 Canvas (сгенерированного в Adobe Animate CC), по событию на чем то вне этого Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, animate, html5-canvas, adobe

Подскажите нюанс работы с Adobe Animate HTML5 Сanvas?

Доступными средствами программирования в Adobe Animate в документе HTML5 Сanvas я сделал интерактивный ролик. Анимация ракеты запускается по клику на кнопке, анимация зацикливается после появления, просто перебрасыванием каретки с нужного кадра назад в нужное место на таймлайне в кадр "loop". 
[Посмотреть](http://jack-dev.zzz.com.ua/toforum/)

По нажатию на другую кнопку, срабатывает переход в кадр "away" и всё, дело сделано.

После публикации, после танцев с бубном всё работает как и предполагалось.
Теперь вопрос.

Как я могу вызывать эти две функции в Canvas, не нажимая на кнопки в объекте Canvas?
А нажимаю на кнопки вне его самого. Т.е. просто навесить как у меня функции на кнопки вне Canvas и по нажатию на них запустить соответствующую функцию в Canvas, которая там имеется?

Как понимаю, используется при публикации create.js и я не смог чего то внятного по ней найти. Там хрен пойми как оно инкапсулируется и создаёт прототип. Раз события там существуют, значит можно как то к ним прорваться, но несколько часов поисков решения ничего не дали. А надо именно управлять с помощью элементов извне Canvas, в идеале что то ему и передавать в параметрах функции. Буду благодарен за помощь.

Вот фидл:
[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/_jack/qL85s1do/)

```
// stage content:
```

(lib.canva = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
    this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

```
// timeline functions:
this.frame_0 = function() {
    this.stop();
    this.buttonGo.addEventListener("click", go.bind(this));
    this.buttonAway.addEventListener("click", away.bind(this));
    function go() {
        this.main.animation.gotoAndPlay("go");
    }
    function away() {
        this.main.animation.gotoAndPlay("away");
    }
}
```

Прошу прощение за огромный код в фидлле, так описывается анимация моя. 
Файл js я вставил просто в тег  первый, чтоб была возможность показать онлайн код, а не подключать со стороны файл.

Интерес представляет только по сути код снизу всего, тот что я скопировал выше. Это те 2 функции, которые нужны, которые так и описаны в Adobe Animate кодом.

**Как мне прописать, обратиться к ним и запустить их средствами простого JS по клику на кнопки которые над Canvas к примеру?**

Для удобства вот архив на проект, если кто решит помочь, так удобней посмотреть, просто запусти index.html

[Download](https://mega.nz/#!FNIwyKDK!L3jrjXxzvfUX1ewZnI5_-0PaBSLjOBOY_yKAiD_r9wk)

Answer (score 1):

У меня получилось вот так:

```
function goFN() {
    stage.children[0].main.animation.gotoAndPlay("go");
}

function awayFN() {
    stage.children[0].main.animation.gotoAndPlay("away");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2015.11.26.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/GVYGqw.js"></script>
<script>
function goFN() {
  stage.children[0].main.animation.gotoAndPlay("go");
}

function awayFN() {
  stage.children[0].main.animation.gotoAndPlay("away");
}

var canvas, stage, exportRoot;

function init() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var loader = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
  loader.installPlugin(createjs.Sound);
  loader.addEventListener("complete", handleComplete);
  loader.loadManifest(lib.properties.manifest);
}

function handleComplete(evt) {
  //This function is always called, irrespective of the content. You can use the variable "stage" after it is created in token create_stage.
  var queue = evt.target;
  var ssMetadata = lib.ssMetadata;
  for (i = 0; i < ssMetadata.length; i++) {
    ss[ssMetadata[i].name] = new createjs.SpriteSheet({
      "images": [queue.getResult(ssMetadata[i].name)],
      "frames": ssMetadata[i].frames
    })
  }
  exportRoot = new lib.canva();
  stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
  stage.addChild(exportRoot);
  stage.enableMouseOver();
  //Registers the "tick" event listener.
  createjs.Ticker.setFPS(lib.properties.fps);
  createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
  //Code to support hidpi screens and responsive scaling.
  (function(isResp, respDim, isScale, scaleType) {
    var lastW, lastH, lastS = 1;
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas);
    resizeCanvas();

    function resizeCanvas() {
      var w = lib.properties.width,
        h = lib.properties.height;
      var iw = window.innerWidth,
        ih = window.innerHeight;
      var pRatio = window.devicePixelRatio,
        xRatio = iw / w,
        yRatio = ih / h,
        sRatio = 1;
      if (isResp) {
        if ((respDim == 'width' && lastW == iw) || (respDim == 'height' && lastH == ih)) {
          sRatio = lastS;
        } else if (!isScale) {
          if (iw < w || ih < h)
            sRatio = Math.min(xRatio, yRatio);
        } else if (scaleType == 1) {
          sRatio = Math.min(xRatio, yRatio);
        } else if (scaleType == 2) {
          sRatio = Math.max(xRatio, yRatio);
        }
      }
      canvas.width = w * pRatio * sRatio;
      canvas.height = h * pRatio * sRatio;
      canvas.style.width = w * sRatio + 'px';
      canvas.style.height = h * sRatio + 'px';
      stage.scaleX = pRatio * sRatio;
      stage.scaleY = pRatio * sRatio;
      lastW = iw;
      lastH = ih;
      lastS = sRatio;
    }
  })(true, 'both', false, 1);
}

function playSound(id, loop) {
  return createjs.Sound.play(id, createjs.Sound.INTERRUPT_EARLY, 0, 0, loop);
}
</script>
<style>
  #canvas {
    position: absolute;
  }

  button {
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: solid 2px #180732;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    left: 50%;
    transition: .3s ease-out
  }

  button:hover {
    border: solid 2px #e4307a;
  }
</style>
<body onload="init();" style="margin:0px;overflow:hidden">

  <canvas id="canvas" width="747" height="522" style="display: block; background-color:rgba(24, 7, 50, 1.00)"></canvas>

  <button onclick="goFN()">Эта кнопка, вызывает функцию, <br>которая должна активировать функцию "go()" в Canvas</button> <br>
  <button onclick="awayFN()">Эта кнопка, вызывает функцию, <br>которая должна активировать функцию "away()" в Canvas</button>

</body>
```

Comment: Спасибо, не додумался так обратиться! 
Супер)

Comment: @JackKosovskiy если что я не думал, я просто открыл отладчик и посмотрел на объект `stage`

Comment: через него тоже пробовал, но ломился выходит к нему root, а надо было вот в children первый

Comment: А я посмотрел какие слушатели висят на объектах-кнопках и сразу все срослось

Comment: Не подскажешь кстати, где почитать что то вменяемое по поводу программирования в этой среде, в adobe animate?

В html5 Canvas документе. Как можно графикой манипулировать. Раньше так работал Flash с AS3 на борту но возможности шире в разы были.
Где почитать, что можно реально на Canvas там запрограммировать, а чего не получится, в сравнении с AS3 или JS?

Например там сразу наткнулся на то, что нельзя запустить какую то функцию в root из другой. Только по событию клик например работает, а запустить её же другую дополнительно уже нет. Хотелось бы в голове уложить арсенал этого инструмента

Comment: Не, я в первый раз его вижу, предпочитаю программировать анимацию ручками, когда это возможно

Comment: я тоже, но тут можно немного дальше в анимации пойти